# Deadlock insert MySQL table

Tags: mysql

**Edit:**
The queries are executed from AWS Lambda and it is a AWS Aurora MySQL compatible database.

It is a M5.large database that has about 70 database connections and around 7% cpu load.
**End Edit.**

We have a dead lock that we are struggling to understand. It happens very rarely and of course when the requests are very close to each other in time.

How can we get better understanding when this happens?

What is best practice in cases like this? Is it ok to accept this and write your code to rerun the query?

Below is more information output from `show engine innodb status`

```
2019-07-31 10:44:08 0x2b0f9939d700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 14 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 457179 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 158871 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 353267
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 363003
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 60860, OS waits 3736
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 278008, OS waits 4241
RW-sx spins 834, rounds 12583, OS waits 94
Spin rounds per wait: 60860.00 RW-shared, 278008.00 RW-excl, 15.09 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-07-29 00:01:57 0x2b122b42b700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 25004785, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1067258, OS thread handle 47346011883264, query id 192217819 160.170.30.251 root update
INSERT INTO logs (date, time, duration, source, another_table_id, date_id) VALUES ('2019-07-29', '00:00:06', 20047, 0, 6793, 3629) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duration = VALUES(duration)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 252 page no 15293 n bits 0 index logs_another_table__c5da8410_uniq of table `database`.`logs` trx id 25004785 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=8; bufptr=0x2b1111b00070; hex= 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 25004783, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1067257, OS thread handle 47345995474688, query id 192217812 160.170.10.38 root update
INSERT INTO logs (date, time, duration, source, another_table_id, date_id) VALUES ('2019-07-28', '23:59:05', 20047, 0, 6792, 3631) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duration = VALUES(duration)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 252 page no 15293 n bits 0 index logs_another_table__c5da1234_uniq of table `database`.`logs` trx id 25004783 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=8; bufptr=0x2b1111b00070; hex= 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 252 page no 15293 n bits 0 index logs_another_table__c5da1234_uniq of table `database`.`logs` trx id 25004783 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=8; bufptr=0x2b1111b00070; hex= 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 30159757
Purge done for trx's n:o < 30159757 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2976
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
0 OS file reads, 0 OS file writes, 0 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 2303461, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 1.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 8204
Log flushed up to   0
Pages flushed up to 8204
Last checkpoint at  8192
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
0 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 0
Dictionary memory allocated 4272484
Buffer pool size   510568
Free buffers       271669
Database pages     238899
Old database pages 88146
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 2287, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 49550, created 189349, written 4828
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 238899, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   255284
Free buffers       136125
Database pages     119159
Old database pages 43966
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1238, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 24722, created 94437, written 68
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 119159, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   255284
Free buffers       135544
Database pages     119740
Old database pages 44180
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1049, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 24828, created 94912, written 4760
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 119740, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=8465, Main thread ID=47357039400704, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 3672324, updated 8861306, deleted 2146, read 1562714829
0.00 inserts/s, 0.50 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.64 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: From where the query runs? I mean from sp or trigger?

Comment: We execute it from AWS Lambda.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `AWS Lambda` anyways the query runs in mysql right?

Comment: Hint: Instead of without checking whether the data exists before Insert check `select` condition with `for update` and do the `insert` or `update`

Comment: Or you can use `insert ignore` to avoid deadlock i hope it works

Comment: This type of dead lock is common in InnoDB engine. so it is better to rerun the query instead of handing it and making it more complex